# My website is getting Corrupted Content Error in firefox on login

Tags: ssl, firefox, nginx, cakephp-2.0

I have a website that is getting corrupted content error when logging into a user account. This error occurs in Firefox. It only occurs when you log into with a clean cache. After you log in once, you get that error, but you get skip past it. Then if you log out, and log back in again, you won't get that problem anymore until you clear the history. After clearing the history and all the cache and going back to the site, and logging in again, the same error occurs. I have seen a different error message on Microsoft Edge in the same scenario, and in Chrome, but I don't remember what they said (I think Edge said the site could not be reached, and chrome said something else). I have been looking around and trying to figure out what the heck is going on and looking for solutions for it, but I'm lost.

I saw one thing on the internet that said it can be solved by clearing cookies, but I don't keep any cookies on this site. And, in my situation - it is fresh history or clearing history that leads to the problem, so this type of solution seems to be the opposite of my situation.

I don't know if it is my ssl certificate. That I bought from namecheap. I don't know if it is something to do with my nginx file. In there I force all http to redirected to https. I don't know if it something to do with my code itself. My server code is coded in CakePHP 2.

Any ideas? I really need to fix this. I am trying to launch this site soon.

Here is my nginx code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my_server_name.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name/web/$request_uri/;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path_to_ssl/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path_to_ssl/my_server_name.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /path_to_ssl_certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    location /web {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/webroot;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /web/app/webroot/index.php;
    }

    server_name my_server_name.com;

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/web/$request_uri/;
    }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        #include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ /.sandbox {
    }

    location ~* \.(?:manifest:appcache|htm?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
    }
```

Update:

I have found another clue to the problem, but have not been able to fix it. In my debug.log I found I was getting this error every time the "Corrupted Content Error" occurred, and at no other times. This is an error in the cakephp AuthComponent:

```
2017-12-31 09:07:28 Notice: Notice (8): Undefined index: element in [/usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php, line 827] 
Trace: 
ErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php, line 230 
AuthComponent::flash() - APP/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php, line 827 
AuthComponent::_unauthenticated() - APP/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php, line 362 
AuthComponent::startup() - APP/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php, line 304 
ObjectCollection::trigger() - CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 128 
CakeEventManager::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php, line 243 
Controller::startupProcess() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 678 
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 189 
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 167 
require - APP/webroot/index.php, line 110 
[main] - ROOT/index.php, line 43
```

The is saying that $this->flash has no index 'element' for this line:

```
$this->Session->setFlash($message, $this->flash['element'], $this->flash['params'], $this->flash['key']);
```

I commented that line out and replaced it with this:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(
                $message,
                array_key_exists('element', $this->flash) ? $this->flash['element'] : 'default',
                array_key_exists('params', $this->flash) ? $this->flash['params'] : array(),
                array_key_exists('key', $this->flash) ? $this->flash['key'] : 'flash'
            );
```

to see if that would fix it.

I still am able to get the corrupted content error if I log out, clear all the cache, reload everything and log back in, but now there is no new error logged in debug.log after making that change. So that's my clue, but I still haven't managed to fix it.

Update: My Request & Response Headers

Here are the Request & Response Headers that firefox shows me when I get this error.

Request Header:

```
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  
keep-alive
Content-Length  
89
Content-Type    
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie  
__cfduid=dc953b88930da52f0ae3f…9-3f87-477c-b65e-380b2034aa54
Host    
my_website_url
Referer 
https://my_website_url.com/web/users/login
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   
1
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
```

And Response:

```
cf-ray: 3d76d2695c6655c4-ORD
content-type    
text/html; charset=UTF-8
date    
Wed, 03 Jan 2018 14:59:26 GMT
location    
///
server  
cloudflare
set-cookie  
CAKEPHP=le4cq2kpkvjqvt5lvcqel8…400; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security   
max-age=15768000
X-Firefox-Spdy  
h2
```

Comment: Why do you set `Strict-Transport-Security` twice?

Comment: Thank you Richard Smith. I didn't even notice that. That is unintentional. Could that be the cause of the problem? I have to try and see if it is or not.

Comment: I removed the first Strict-Transport-Security line and restarted my nginx, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you make a curl -D - request with your auth params and post the response HTTP headers here?

Comment: @ffeast, I have posted the request and response http headers that I get when encountering the problem, as per your request.

Comment: @ffeast, By asking for the request & response http headers, you helped me solve the problem. Sorry, I didn't post them sooner, then you might have had a chance to help me further and win the bounty. I wish I could reward the bounty to both you and Eugene Adell.

Comment: @user904542, never mind, glad to hear the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you believe you are not using any cookie, the authentication itself probably stores one cookie. If clearing the cache makes this problem to happen, this means that accessing one resource is problematic but is later solved by another call.

some tips for debugging your config :

- As your ssl stapling configuration is incomplete, try removing both directives ssl_stapling and ssl_stapling_verify
- Remove the http2 directives in your listeners
- The corrupted content can come from an infinite loop and there are 2 301 redirects in your config. Try accessing directly to the https website, both with server_name and my_server_name.com as you have these two names. If we still don't find the cause, remove the redirect in the :80 listener and browse your site without any SSL at all.

Comment: Thank you, I will examine your suggestions. Also, I have added the request & response headers I get when I encounter the error.

Comment: the location response header is problematic : /// ;

Comment: The problem with trying my site without any SSL at all is that it has a user registration and user account system in it, where new users can create their own account with a username and password, and then sign in.

Comment: it's up to you to know whether you are testing a DEV site or a PROD ; From your response headers, an empty location means a bad redirection. This is probably the application itself that doesn't know where to redirect, and not in the nginx config as I was thinking from the elements you provided. Check your application if it has a default landing page after authentication (FQDN, default page ,..)

Comment: I don't know why, but it turned out that `$this->Auth->redirectUrl()` (I am using CakePHP 2), which I was using for redirecting, had that '///' in it. I changed it to redirect to `$this->components['Auth']['loginRedirect']` and now I don't get that problem anymore, even after clearing my cache (with my nginx configuration the same as before).

I think I should reward the bounty to you, since you helped me find the error, but ffeast also helped me find the error, by getting me to post the request & response headers, so I wish I could reward a bounty to both of you.

Comment: thanks for the reward - it takes time to answer questions such as yours ; I'll up vote ffeast's comment.